# How to add html tag attribute in bootstrap 5 popover setAttribute()?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

I am trying to add html tag in popover setAttribute() in bootstrap 5 but they show tag in content and not apply it as attribute.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mx-2" data-bs-container="body" data-bs-toggle="popover" id="popcart" data-bs-placement="bottom" data-bs-content="cart here">
        Cart(<span id="cart">0</span>)
</button>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p"
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

And in javascript

```
    var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]'))
  var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function (popoverTriggerEl) {
    return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl)
  })
  document.getElementById("popcart").setAttribute('data-bs-content', '<h5>Cart for your items in my shopping cart</h5>');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at all the options for popovers.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/popovers/#options

HTML is set to false by default to help prevent xss attacks. You can set this to true when instantiating your Popover, and your code will work as expected.

```js
var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]'))
var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function (popoverTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl, 
    
    // options object as a second param
    {
      html: true
    }

  )
})
document.getElementById("popcart").setAttribute('data-bs-content', '<h5>Cart for your items in my shopping cart</h5>');
```